# Exception while accessing RfcommDeviceService from a wearable in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, uwp, windows-mobile

**Here is what I have,**

1. A bluetooth wearable (MyoArm band).
2. Windows Mobile 10 with anniversary update.

Both of them are paired properly.

**Now, here is what I am trying to do,**

1. I am trying to enumerate the list of all services exposed by the bluetooth device connected to my windows mobile.
2. I would then like to read input streams, if the service provides one.

I went though MSDN documentation and here is what I have done so far.

**P.S. I have added Bluetooth access to the capabilities in the application manifest.**

```
    private async void OnReceiveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
        IList<DeviceInformation> myBluetoothDevices = new List<DeviceInformation>();
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            if (device.Name.Contains("myo"))
            {
                var trace = string.Format("Name: {2} \t  Paired: {3} \t Kind: {1} \t Id: {0}", device.Id, device.Kind, device.Name, device.Pairing?.IsPaired);
                builder.AppendLine(trace);
                myBluetoothDevices.Add(device);
            }
        }

        foreach (var myBluetoothDevice in myBluetoothDevices)
        {
            try
            {
                if (myBluetoothDevice != null)
                {
                    var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(myBluetoothDevice.Id);
                    // TODO: Read input stream somehow here!!!
                    log.Text = builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Name: {0} \t Id: {1} \t Device Info Name: {2} \t Connection Host Name: {3} \t Service Id: {4}", service.Device.Name, service.Device.DeviceId, service.Device.DeviceInformation.Name, service.ConnectionHostName, service.ServiceId.Uuid)).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                log.Text = builder.ToString();
            } 
        }
    }
```

When I run the code and click the "Receive" button, I get an exception while calling the RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync method.

**Exception: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)**

Am I missing something here? I am new to programming with bluetooth devices, so am I approaching the problem correctly?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845320/uwp-serialdevice-fromidasync-throws-element-not-found-exception-from-hresult?rq=1

Comment: Did you succeed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please ensure the devices queried out by device name are Bluetooth devices since you find all devices not only Bluetooth devices for query. For find Bluetooth devices, [`DeviceWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.aspx) is recommended and sample code please reference `StartUnpairedDeviceWatcher()` method in [this file](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat/cs/Scenario1_ChatClient.xaml.cs).

Secondly, I'm not sure why `RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(myBluetoothDevice.Id);` cannot get a [`RfcommDeviceService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice.aspx) instance but the official sample is not using this method for getting the service.  It got the BluetoothDeivce firstly and then [`GetRfcommServices`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.getrfcommservicesforidasync) from the device.

```
 var bluetoothDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(myBluetoothDevice.Id);
 var rfcommServices = await bluetoothDevice.GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(Constants.RfcommChatServiceUuid)); 
 if (rfcommServices.Services.Count > 0)
 {
     service = rfcommServices.Services[0];
 }
```

The [RfcommServiceId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommserviceid.aspx) is same as [RfcommServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn263511) created. Details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat) which I have tested can run and find `RfcommDeviceService` instance successfully.

Comment: I kind of followed your approach. I am now using DeviceWatcher and then I am querrying the device. I am able to find the device and when I query the services, it returns null. 

I am trying this out by paring my PC to a Pebble Watch. My objective is to write a pebble companion app for windows phone and any martial to help me out would be appreciated!

Comment: @sudarsanyes, please try to test the official sample. The sample shows the services provider need to listen for the clients. I'm not familiar with your Pebble Watch, does it listen for clients? Did you get the right `RfcommServiceId`? For these I cannot help you more. Also please try to use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.getrfcommservicesasync) method which get all services to see if you can got.